# Update tableadapter database in Visual Studio

Tags: sql, vb.net

Im trying to get my program to add a row to the database using event handlers and tableadapters. I can successfully add a row to the database, but it doesnt save when I click the "btnRefresh" button. Here is the code for the event handler.

```
Private Sub btnRefresh_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRefresh.Click
    Try
        Validate()
        CarsBindingSource.EndEdit()
        CarsTableAdapter.Update(Me.ABVDataSet.Cars)
        MsgBox("Refreshed Successfully")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Update failed")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you call AcceptChanges on that Cars table or the ABVDataSet?

Comment: AcceptChanges? No I didnt. How would I do that and what would that do?

Comment: The Update method choose what to update looking at the DataRowState of each row in the Cars table. AcceptChanges reset this state to "Unchanged" and thus the Update does nothing on these rows. I suggest to use the debugger to check if the Cars table contains any row with the property DataRowState different from Unchanged

Comment: There are only three possible outcomes when you make that `Update` call. Firstly, the call might fail, in which case an exception will be thrown and it will tell you what went wrong. Secondly, the call might succeed and return zero, in which case there were no changes in your `DataTable` to save. Thirdly, the call might succeed and return a non-zero value, in which case the call succeeded and the changes were saved. Which is it in your case? Most likely it's the third and you're just not looking for the changes properly, which is very common.

Comment: The changes get put into the tableadapter, but if i exit out of the program and go back in to see if the changes were saved, theyre not there

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub btnRefresh_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRefresh.Click Try Validate() CarsBindingSource.EndEdit() CarsTableAdapter.Update(ABVDataSet,"table_name") MsgBox("Refreshed Successfully") Catch ex As Exception MsgBox("Update failed") End Try End Sub
```